# Is there a way to programmatically detect if Stage Manager is enabled in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios16

I am working on a POC to see if I can programmatically deactivate the Stage Manager feature for an IPAD app. This has been part of the iOS 16 beta release. Below are the 2 areas I started focusing on

1. Detect if Stage Manager is enabled
2. See if there are ways to disable the Stage Manager feature

After going through a lot of articles, am unable to figure out any API in Xamarin that would help me detect if the Stage Manager is activated. I tried below code snippet, but this doesn't seem to be giving me the correct results.

```
 var appWindow = application
            .ConnectedScenes
            .ToArray()
            .OfType<UIWindowScene>()
            .SelectMany(scene => scene.Windows)
            .FirstOrDefault(window => window.IsKeyWindow);

 var screenHeight = appWindow.Window.WindowScene.Screen.Bounds.Height;
 var windowHeight = appWindow.Window.Screen.Bounds.Height;
 bool stageManager = screenHeight > windowHeight;
```

The above snippet was derived from one of the reference articles I had found when I was searching for APIs

```
var isStageManager: Bool {
    guard UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad,
       let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate,
       let screenHeight = sceneDelegate.window?.windowScene?.screen.bounds.height,
       let windowHeight = sceneDelegate.window?.bounds.height else { return false }
    return screenHeight > windowHeight
  }
```

Note: Tried changing the way screenHeight/windowHeight was retrieved as shown below. But this retrieved the same values for both variables though the stage manager was enabled. Has anyone tried doing this or any references that can help me get a step closer to the solution?

```
var screenHeight = appWindow.WindowScene.Screen.Bounds.Height;
var windowHeight = appWindow.Screen.Bounds.Height;
```

Comment: even if you could detect it, I don't think there is any way to programatically disable it

Comment: Thanks, Jason for the response. Is there anything wrong with the way I have coded to detect it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try to see if it helps:

```
var sceneDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication
            .ConnectedScenes
            .ToArray()
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Delegate as SceneDelegate;

var screenHeight = sceneDelegate.Window.WindowScene.Screen.Bounds.Height;
var windowHeight = sceneDelegate.Window.Bounds.Height;
bool stageManager = screenHeight > windowHeight;
```

Comment: Is there any API that could tell us that the stage-manager is enabled? Instead of this code check !!